# Problem opening .dvi files

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, latex, evince

I would like to know why my Lubuntu 11.10 does not open my .dvi files created with Latex.

Please, can anybody help me solve this problem?

---

When I use `evince L1.dvi`, in the terminal, the `evince` opens but not the file and the messages on the terminal are:

```
    evince L1.dvi 

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-buttons.css:159:10: Expected valid border

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:102:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:117:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:134:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:153:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:165:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:175:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:186:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:198:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:208:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:218:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found

(evince:3556): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:223:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-texlive/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c.

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmti10
mktexpk: Permissão negada
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
page: Warning: font `cmti10' at 600x600 not found, trying `cmr10' instead

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10
mktexpk: Permissão negada
page: Warning: font `cmti10' not found, trying metric files instead

kpathsea: Running mkofm cmti10
mkofm: Permissão negada

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmti10
mktextfm: Permissão negada
page: Warning: metric file for `cmti10' not found, trying `cmr10' instead

kpathsea: Running mkofm cmr10
mkofm: Permissão negada

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmr10
mktextfm: Permissão negada
page: Error: could not load font `cmti10'
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-texlive/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c.

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmti10
mktexpk: Permissão negada
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
page: Warning: font `cmti10' at 600x600 not found, trying `cmr10' instead

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10
mktexpk: Permissão negada
page: Warning: font `cmti10' not found, trying metric files instead

kpathsea: Running mkofm cmti10
mkofm: Permissão negada

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmti10
mktextfm: Permissão negada
page: Warning: metric file for `cmti10' not found, trying `cmr10' instead

kpathsea: Running mkofm cmr10
mkofm: Permissão negada

kpathsea: Running mktextfm cmr10
mktextfm: Permissão negada
page: Error: could not load font `cmti10'

(evince:3556): EvinceView-CRITICAL **: ev_document_model_set_document: assertion `EV_IS_DOCUMENT (document)' failed

(evince:3556): EvinceDocument-CRITICAL **: ev_document_get_n_pages: assertion `EV_IS_DOCUMENT (document)' failed

(evince:3556): EvinceDocument-CRITICAL **: ev_document_get_max_page_size: assertion `EV_IS_DOCUMENT (document)' failed
```

Comment: more details required, including:  What do you mean by "does not open"?  How are you trying to open them? What exactly are you doing? What exact response are you getting?  How does that differ from the expected response?

Comment: @CraigSanders, thanks. I updated above. Sorry for so many errors. First, I try to open dvi files with double click on it.

Comment: @jasonwyran, please, how did you create that minipage for the codes? Thanks for editing.

Comment: it looks like some kind of permissions problem - google says that 'Permissão negada' means 'Permission denied'

Comment: Looks like this Ubuntu bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-bin/+bug/1010909

Comment: @Renan, you are right. Everything there is so similar to my problems. So,I guess that there is no solution yet, right?

Comment: @Sigur from that bug: "I have the same problem even after installation of texlive-fonts-recommended package. I should execute all 'mktexpk' commands in the error messages with 'sudo' to see the correct fonts on evince." Worth a try.

Comment: @Renan, no, it does not work. Other problems, as (evince:3788): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-bars.css:223:16: Themeing engine 'adwaita' not found
Failed to get bus connection: A linha de comandos "dbus-launch --autolaunch=0d11d198238a6cd852340fdf0000000b --binary-syntax --close-stderr" saiu com status de saída não-zero, 1: EOF in dbus-launch reading address from bus daemon\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu sets up evince to use AppArmor, which prevents it from accessing certain files even though the files have appropriate permissions. See [Evince fails to start because it cannot read .Xauthority](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42385/evince-fails-to-start-because-it-cannot-read-xauthority) for a different but related problem.

Do you have a custom TeX installation? If so, evince is probably preventing from writing the font files by AppArmor. See [Ubuntu bug 846639](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/846639), which shows how to fix the AppArmor configuration for your system.

A simple workaround is to view the file once in another viewer such as `xdvi`, so that the fonts are generated. Then evince will be able to read them. Or run

```
allneeded L1.dvi
```

You can run the commands `allcm` and `allec` to generate some common fonts.