# Use SSH key authentication with custom user $HOME

Tags: ssh, permissions, sshd, key-authentication

I have some users which have different $HOME directories than `/home/`.

The user homes are under `/pkg/home`and `/pkg` owner is a different user, but all users have group access to `/pkg`. It seems that SSHD will restrict access to `authorized_keys` (e.g. `/pkg/home/usera/.sshd/authorized_keys`) because the user is not owner of the full path.

Is there any option for `sshd_config` to change this restriction?

Comment: I don't think that this is the reason. If $HOME is /home/usera the  user also will not be owner of the full path (the meaning is usera will not be owner of /home). can you show the `ls -ld /pkg /pkg/home /pkg/home/usera /pkg/home/usera/.ssh  /pkg/home/usera/authorized_keys` for a problem user?

Comment: Thx, you are right. File permissions were correct, both 700. Problem was caused by SELinux. I found out that I had to run the command 'restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh' https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476362

Comment: @marquies, feel free to [add your solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48099/use-ssh-key-authentification-with-custom-user-home#comment67121_48100) as an Answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all or nothing: if you turn the `StrictModes` option off, sshd will never check any file modes. There's no way to say that certain odd cases are ok, such as a group-writable directory (which is ok if the user is alone in the group).

OpenSSH checks the permissions and ownership of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and its containing directories recursing upwards. However, it stops the comparison when it reaches the home directory. For example, in the classical arrangement where the authorization file is `/home/joe/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/home/joe` is the user's home directory, only `/home/joe/.ssh/authorized_keys`, `/home/joe/.ssh` and `/home/joe` are checked.

So while your scenario is highly dubious (`/pkg` should be owned by root, with additional group permissions if required), it should not impact ssh.

If any symbolic links are involved, note that ssh expands all symlinks before starting its checks.

The system logs might have relevant information. Check if your failed login attempts cause any log message.

Check that your version of ssh performs the same checks as mine (I looked at the source of OpenSSH 5.5p1) by running a debug mode daemon on a custom port (`sshd -d -p 2222`). Use `strace -f -efile sshd -d -p 2222` if necessary to check which files' permission the server checks. If these permission checks aren't the issue, adding more `-d` flags might throw some light.

If you have AppArmor, there's also the possibility that it is restricting the ssh server to reading files in users' `.ssh` directories. If you have AppArmor and home directories in a nonstandard location, you'll need to update AppArmor policies (not just for SSH). See [Evince fails to start because it cannot read .Xauthority](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42385/evince-fails-to-start-because-it-cannot-read-xauthority/42386#42386).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter who owns /pkg/. If it would be owned by `usera` then you would have problems with `userb` etc. So it must be something else that prevents SSHD from using `authorized_keys` file. You have to check if this file is writable **only** by the owner and if it is owned by proper user. The same applies all parent directories.

Comment: Thx, you are right. File permissions were correct, both 700. Problem was caused by SELinux. I found out that I had to run the command 'restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh' https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476362

Comment: I'm glad you where able to find that out. It's a good idea to mention in question that you are using SELinux if you have any problems with permissions, access etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using '/data' as base dir for the user directories. For me, it was not enough to run 'restorecon -R -v ~/.ssh'. First, I had to run

```
# semanage fcontext -a -e /home /data
```

as root, and then (also as root as the /data directory contained a root-owned directory)

```
# restorecon -R -v /data
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, make sure to check the sshd logs and that the correct permissions are set on the folders and file:

```
$ chown usera /pkg/home/usera
$ chmod go-w  /pkg/home/usera
$ chmod 700   /pkg/home/usera/.ssh
$ chmod 600   /pkg/home/usera/.ssh/authorized_keys
```