# Evince: Unable to init server: Could not Connect: Connection refused

Tags: x11, display, gtk, evince

When running

```
$ evince a.pdf
```

I receive the following error message.

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

I have an X Session running and DISPLAY=:0

Specifying the display

```
$ evince --display=:0
```

yields a similar error message

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display: :0
```

I am running Debian 10 Buster.

Comment: Is there an X11 server installed on the Debian system?

Comment: Yes. An X11 server is installed and running.

Comment: Maybe it's https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42385/evince-fails-to-start-because-it-cannot-read-xauthority ?